# Unable to use Weld for Context and Dependency Injection (CDI) in my stand alone Java SE application

Tags: java, cdi, weld

I am trying to make a standalone Java SE application with CDI. I followed [this](https://randling.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/cdi-in-java-se/) article and I am using Weld. However when I try to instantiate `Weld weld = new Weld();` I am getting the following ClassNotFound error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/weld/environment/ContainerInstanceFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.agorava.socializer.Test.main(Test.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.weld.environment.ContainerInstanceFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 more
```

I checked the weld-se JAR an it doesn't contain this Interface. What is the issue here? Thanks in advance.

Following is my Test class org.agorava.socializer.Test

```
public class Test  {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Weld w = new Weld();
        WeldContainer factory = w.initialize();
        OAuthLifeCycleService service = factory.instance().select(OAuthLifeCycleService.class).get();
        System.out.println(service.getCurrentService());        

    }

}
```

Comment: Also have a look at the official tutorial: http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#_java_se

Comment: Which Weld version are you using?

Comment: How do you run your application?

Comment: I tried with 1.1.8 and 2.3.2. I am running it as Java Application

Comment: Please provide more details how you run the application. How do you setup the classpath? Are you using the Exec Maven Plugin?

Comment: Please also show us the code of org.agorava.socializer.Test around line 59.

Comment: Done. When I used maven to build, Maven couldn't update the path. Then I manually added the Jar.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your problem is related to version "org.jboss.weld.environment.ContainerInstanceFactory" interface is available in newer version (Weld 3)
refer https://github.com/weld/core/commit/36563d252a4a2375692d7669e7a523bb6ba89136

Try updating your version of weld-se.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while writing unit tests.
Here is the answer on [github](https://github.com/BrynCooke/cdi-unit/issues/119) and here is the related part in my pom file:

```
    <!--Enable CDI in tomcat-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Enables unit testing CDI apps-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jglue.cdi-unit</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-unit</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--This is required implicitly for cdi-unit 4.0.1-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```